# mysqli_stmt_init is throwing a warning in PhpStorm

Tags: php, phpstorm, signature

I'm trying to understand whether I did something wrong with a `mysqli_stmt_init` method.

Everything is working but PhpStorm keeps showing `Method call uses 1 parameters, but method signature uses 0 parameters`. What does that mean?

I have triple checked everything and googled for quite some time with no results on why PhpStorm is throwing this warning.

```
function mysqliConnect(){
    $connect = mysqli_connect(dbhost,dbuser,dbpass,dbname);
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo `Failed to connect to MySql with erro: ` . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    mysqli_set_charset($connect, 'utf8mb4');
    return $connect;
}

    $connect = mysqliConnect();
    $uid = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $uid);

    $query = "SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE uid = ?";
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($connect); // <-- WARNING
    if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $query)) {
        echo 'SQL Error';
    } else {
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'i',$uid);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
    }
```

Comment: Since you are using the procedural of `mysqli_stmt_init()`, which indeed takes a single argument, I think phpstorm really reports an incorrect warning in this case. If you look at the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.stmt-init.php you will see that the object oriented counter part takes no argument at all. So, if you were do write something like `$connect->stmt_init($connect);` then the warning would be valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you CTRL + click on the `mysqli_stmt_init()` function you will see the embedded stubs that JetBrains uses for intellisense.

```
/**
 * Initializes a statement and returns an object for use with mysqli_stmt_prepare
 * @link http://fr2.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.stmt-init.php
 * @return mysqli_stmt
 */
function mysqli_stmt_init () {}
```

These only have an implementation without parameters (the one used by the object oriented version) and not the procedural version which takes a single mysqli argument.

This is obviously a bug, but the way Jetbrains Intellisense works (with embedded stubs) makes it very difficult to solve, because the same method cannot have multiple implementations with different method signatures in the stub files.

Comment: You can participate in stubs updating. If you're interested please follow instructions at https://github.com/JetBrains/phpstorm-stubs/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md